# What is the limit to URI length Google displays in search results

Tags: url, hyperlink, seo

I'm devising a segment based URI system. It is important to me to add certain keywords to URI, TITLE, headlines etc. So I was wondering what is the maximum length of a URI that does not have a query string attached that Google will display within search results?

I explored this a bit already. It seems that it is a factor whether Google's cache has been disallowed or not. I searched for 'site:dpreview.com' and 'site:spiegel.de' to get examples. dpreview.com allows caching spiegel.de does not.

With dpreview.com the URI www.dpreview.com/reviews/Q110superzoomgroup/ (44 characters) will be shortened in the seach results to: www.dpreview.com/.../Q110superzoomgroup/

With spiegel.de the URI www.spiegel.de/thema/landtagswahl_rheinland_pfalz_2011/ (55 characters) will be displayed completely.

For non segment based URIs the risk to be shortened seems significantly less. I searched 'site:www.internet-empire.com' (not affiliated with them just some site with long host name and long URIs). the have caching left on and still URIs like
www.internet-empire.com/internet-presence-vs-internet-marketing.htm (67 characters) are displayed in whole. The 'Similar' link gets omitted by Google here.

So the question is: Is segment based the way to go, if so are there any limits to rely on  in terms of URL length and is it best practise to have the most important keywords at the end of the URI or is it as with the title tag where things will become less important to the right. Note we are not talking about extremely long URIs maybe up to 90 characters if five keywords have to be included.

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google is constantly testing this for usability/relevancy purposes - they want to show the visitor that the URL matches in someway their query.

So your answer is hidden in the examples you have shown (i.e. there is no one length).

Different URL constructs will be shown differently and truncated/edited to:

1. show that the URL filename matches the some/all/part of query (for highlighting)
2. removes redundant intermediary segments/folders (when not matching query)
3. show breadcrumbs in URL construct when page coded appropriately

It's an interesting observation you have made about cacheing being allowed or not, but since this is not standard practice, you'd be better served following the more common practice.

Remember that the URL is only shown for (searcher) validation purposes and will only have a (minimal) impact on Click Through Rates (CTR). Page title and description are more worthy of your time in this respect.

The final takeaway is that you should, where possible, make your URL and file-path as short and relevant as possible. How it's constructed (segmented/hyphenated etc) will all be handled appropriate to the search query.